# use DIR command output in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dir

I use command :

```
dir D:\ /b /A:D-H
```

and output is for example:

- Photos
- Wallpapers
- My Personal Data

and.. I want to set varialeble on this folders as:

---

set SOMEFOLDER=folder1

---

set SOMEFOLDER2=folder2

and ect..

How can I do this?

Comment: By folder1 and folder2 do you mean e.g. Photos and Wallpapers respectively?

Comment: Consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following for a batch file in the same directory as the folders:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0
for /d %%i in (*) do set /a num+=1&set SOMEFOLDER!num!=%%i
echo SOMEFOLDER1 = %SOMEFOLDER1%
echo SOMEFOLDER2 = %SOMEFOLDER2%
pause
```

If you need the batch file in a different directory or want to change some options, use this instead:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir D:\ /b /a:D-H') do set /a num+=1&set SOMEFOLDER!num!=%%i
echo SOMEFOLDER1 = %SOMEFOLDER1%
echo SOMEFOLDER2 = %SOMEFOLDER2%
pause
```